# If every cover consisting of closed sets has a finite subcover,

Tags: real-analysis

Let's call a set **Pseudo compact** if it has the property that every closed cover (a cover consisting of closed sets) has a finite subcover.

**Questions.**

(a) Is **Pseudo Compact** in this case the same as **Anti-Compact**?

(b) Then how can we describe the **Pseudo-Compact** subsets of Real Numbers?

Comment: (b) In terms of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$: every set $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ can be covered by $S = \cup_{x\in S} \{x\}$. (a) $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual discrete topology is anti-compact. But it is not pseudo compact.

Comment: A subset of a T1 space is pseudo compact iff it's finite.